# Apply mean value theorem for inequalities

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $p, q$ be positive real numbers such that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$. For real numbers $a\geq0, b\geq0$ show that $$ab\leq\frac{a^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q}$$

I am newly studying calculus in college.

I went through the proof present at http://www.math.ust.hk/~majhu/Math203/Rudin/Homework23.pdf

But I couldn't understand it properly. I am looking for much simpler proof.

Comment: I feel compelled to add, this inequality is deeply important in mathematics, and having the proof memorized would help you a lot in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

You can start from the inequality:
$$
x^{\lambda} y^{1-\lambda} \leq \lambda x + (1-\lambda) y,
\qquad
x,y>0,\ \lambda\in [0,1],
$$
that can be proved, for example, using the concavity and the monotonicity of the $\log$ function:
$$
\log(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \geq \lambda \log x + (1-\lambda)\log y
= \log(x^\lambda y^{1-\lambda}).
$$

Then you can use this inequality with $x=a^p$, $y=b^q$, $\lambda = 1/p$, $1-\lambda = 1/q$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to show the inequality is to use [Young's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young's_inequality_for_products).

Young's inequality states that if $f$ is a continuous and strictly increasing function on some interval $[0, c]$ with $c > 0$ and $f(0) = 0$ then for all $a \in [0, c]$ and $b \in [0, f(c)]$
$$\int^a_0 f(x) \, dx + \int^b_0 f^{-1} (x) \, dx \geqslant ab,$$
with equality holding if and only if $b = f(a)$. Here $f^{−1}$ denotes the inverse function of $f$.

Young’s inequality is so general that many interesting inequalities can
be derived from it. In particular, if the function $f(x) = x^{p-1}$ for $p > 1$ is taken in Young's inequality the result you seek immediately follows.